# ModelIO Framework Not Working

Tags: swift, .obj, metal, metalkit

I'm trying to import 3D model files and render them with `Metal` using `ModelIO` and `MetalKit` (on OS X 10.11), but the behavior I'm seeing from these frameworks (specifically `ModelIO`) is not as expected.

I can import `.obj` files and convert them to `MetalKit` meshes without causing any errors, but the mesh (at least under rendering), seems to just be a large fan of triangles all emanating from a single point. The model in the screenshot below is supposed to be a subdivided version of the "Suzanne" monkey head:
[image: Incorrectly imported .obj file]

On inspection, the vertex indices of the `MDLSubmesh` from the imported file don't make any sense. Successive sets of indices keep referring to the vertex at index `0`, sometimes multiple times in the same set of indices, which would explain the appearance during rendering. I have confirmed that this `.obj` file imports fine into other applications.

I have tried importing other 3D file formats (all officially supported by the framework), but any formats other than `.obj` cause an uncaught `NSException` on the call to `MDLAsset`'s `init()`.

I'm working with Xcode 7.2 and targeting OS X 10.11.

Comment: It's hard to tell from what you've posted , but there's some chance this is a ModelIO bug. I'd recommend [filing it](http://bugreport.apple.com) and attaching the obj file just in case.

Comment: @rickster Thanks. I just tried writing my own code to parse the file and it works fine (without rendering modifications), so the issue I'm having with ModelIO is either a bug or me not understanding how to use the API correctly (though I believe I am).

Comment: Post some code how are you using MetalIO and how do you draw it. Try using this mesh in MetalIO sample from Apple website.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been also experiencing similar issues, although I'm a rookie in Metal, I figured a few things out.

I was trying to import the Melita teapot, but I was also having an "explosion" of faces, instead of the iconic tea-brewing device. The solution came to me after reading the documentation of `MDLVertexBufferLayout`, which reads:

> A mesh may store vertex data in either a structure of arrays model,
>   where data for each vertex attribute (such as vertex position or
>   surface normal) lies in a separate vertex buffer, or in an array of
>   structures model, where multiple vertex attributes share the same
>   buffer.
>
> - In a structure of arrays, the mesh’s vertexBuffers array contains
>     several MDLMeshBuffer objects, and the mesh’s vertexDescriptor object
>     contains a separate MDLVertexBufferLayout object for each buffer.
> - In an array of structures, the mesh contains a single vertex buffer,
>     and its descriptor contains a single vertex buffer layout object. To
>     identify which bytes in the buffer refer to which vertices and vertex
>     attributes, use the layout’s stride together with the format and
>     offset properties of the descriptor’s vertex attributes.

By looking at the `.layouts` and `.attributes` properties of the default implementation of the `MDLVertexDescriptor`, they are creating one buffer for each attribute type (like in the quote above, the first case), where I wanted to use the intermixed mode.

I manually set up the `.layouts` and `.attributes` with my own arrays and then, voila I got... half a melita pot?

[image: Half-baked implementation... get it!?]

```
class func setup(meshWithDevice device: MTLDevice) -> MTKMesh
{
    // Allocator
    let allocator = MTKMeshBufferAllocator(device: device)

    // Vertex Descriptor, tells the MDLAsset how to layout the buffers
    let vertexDescriptor = MDLVertexDescriptor()

    // Vertex Buffer Layout, tells how many buffers will be used, and the stride of its structs
    // (the init(stide: Int) crashes in the Beta)
    let vertexLayout = MDLVertexBufferLayout()
    vertexLayout.stride = MemoryLayout<Vertex>.size

    // Apply the Layouts
    vertexDescriptor.layouts = [vertexLayout]

    // Apply the attributes, in my case, position and normal (float4 x2)
    vertexDescriptor.attributes =
    [
        MDLVertexAttribute(name: MDLVertexAttributePosition, format: MDLVertexFormat.float4, offset: 0, bufferIndex: 0),
        MDLVertexAttribute(name: MDLVertexAttributeNormal, format: MDLVertexFormat.float4, offset: MemoryLayout<float4>.size, bufferIndex: 0)
    ]

    var error : NSError? = nil

    // Load the teapot
    let asset = MDLAsset(url: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "teapot", withExtension: "obj")!, vertexDescriptor: vertexDescriptor, bufferAllocator: allocator, preserveTopology: true, error: &error)

    if let error = error
    {
        print(error)
    }

    // Obtain the teapot Mesh
    let teapotModel = asset.object(at: 0) as! MDLMesh

    // Convert into MetalKit Mesh, insted of ModelIO
    let teapot = try! MTKMesh(mesh: teapotModel, device: device)

    return teapot
}
```

(Swift 3.0 in XCode 8 Beta 6)

I'll update my post if I manage to render the whole thing.

### Edit: Works Now

[image: Holy shi---]

Whelp, the bug was on my end, I was wrong in the Index count:

```
//// Buffers
renderPass.setVertexBuffer(mesh.vertexBuffers[0].buffer, offset: 0, at: 0)
renderPass.setVertexBuffer(uniformBuffer, at: 1)

let submesh   = mesh.submeshes[0]
let indexSize = submesh.indexType == .uInt32 ? 4 : 2

//// Draw Indices
renderPass.drawIndexedPrimitives(submesh.primitiveType,
                                 indexCount:  submesh.indexBuffer.length / indexSize,
                                 indexType:   submesh.indexType,
                                 indexBuffer: submesh.indexBuffer.buffer,
                                 indexBufferOffset: 0)
```

The problem was with `let indexSize = submesh.indexType == .uInt32 ? 4 : 2`, before I was doing `32 : 16` on the right side, but the `.length` property comes in Bytes not bits, so dumb.

Anyway, I managed to load an Obj file with Metal, so the problem is either: the one I mentioned above of the individual buffering per attribute, or an entirely different issue in your code.